# Using variable reference to point to static member of some other class

Tags: java, reference

I have a class `Cache` which picks up `List<SomeObject> someObjectList` from DB and stores it in static variable.

Now I have another thread A which uses this List as follows

```
class A extends Thread{
  private List<SomeObject> somobjLst;

  public A(){
    somobjLst = Cache.getSomeObjectList();
  }

 void run(){
  //somobjLst used  in a loop here, no additong are done it , but its value is used
 }
}
```

1. Now if at some point of time if some objects are added to `Cache.someObjectList` will it reflect in class A. I think it should as A only holds a refrence to it.
2. Will there will be any problem in A's code when content of `Cache.someObjectList` change?

EDIT:
As per suggestions :
if i make

```
  void run (){
  while(true){
     synchronized(someObjList){


    }
     try{
     Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
     }catch(Exception e){
     }
  }
 }
```

will this solve problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, the changes will be reflected in class `A` as well. Exactly as you say: `A` holds a *reference* to the exact same object as `Cache`.
2. Yes, it *can* lead to a problem if `A` doesn't expect it to change. It **also** can lead to a problem if the `List` implementation is not thread safe (most general-purpose implementations are *not thread-safe*!). Accessing a non-thread-safe data structure from two threads at the same time can lead to very nasty problems.

Comment: In my case if new elements are added or deleted i As logic wont be affected.The doubt it if A does SomeObject s = lst.get(i)  and now A is working with s.Now when a is working with s if Cache delete same object?What will happen in this case?

Comment: @akshay: if they do that at the same time (i.e. without some synchronization in place), then **anything** can happen. The result can range from "nothing special" over "inexplicable exceptions happen" to "endless loop in deletion code of the `List` implementation".

Comment: But *please* google around a bit for "thread-safety". The topics is **much** to large to be discussed in the comments here (or even explained in a single, long answer).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you are holding reference to collection in your thread. If collection is changed while you are iterating over it in thread `ConcurrentModificationException` will be thrown.

To avoid it you have to use some kind of synchronization mechanism. For example synchronize the iteration over collection and its modification done in other thread using `synchronize(collection)`.

This is a kind of "pessimistic" locking.

Other possibility is to use collections from `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: If inside run method if i have while loop which makes the thread sleep for 1 min after each iteration.And inside while i have my logic.So i i make code within while to be synchronized on my collection referance as synchronized(somobjLst){ logic } .Will this make cache class to wait when it tries to update someObjectList  till iteration completes?

Comment: The `ConcurrentModificationException` will be thrown **if you're lucky**. It could just as easily fail with some strange condition or end in an endless loop.

Comment: i added some code to solve the problem.Will it solve the same?